# Import in getServerSideProp ends up in client bundle #53487

Tags: next.js

I am investigating why I see `crypto-browserify` polyfill in my client bundle.
In my code, I have something like this

```ts
// /pages/[myPage].tsx
import { crypto } from 'crypto';

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<MyProps> = async (context) => {
  // use crypto package here
}

// not using crypto anywhere else
```

In this case, crypto import is done at the top of the page file, but is only used within `getServerSideProps` context.
Will it still end up in the client bundle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any imports inside the getServerSideProps function should not end up in the client bundle.

[Here is the reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763714/does-nextjs-include-libraries-that-are-referenced-only-in-getserversideprops-in)

Comment: Thanks, I am still seeing it in the bundle, so I am not sure where it is coming from

Comment: I found the issue, I had a helper file to make api calls and it was mixing server side api calls and client side. That's why it ended up in the client bundle. 

This tools helped find the issue for anyone wondering:
https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/